# How to access Map Key/value in DAML?

Tags: dictionary, daml

Trying to replace an element in the map but not sure how to get it done. Not sure what to do to access the key or the value.

Tried the below code but it complains that key or value is not recognized.

```js
let map : Map Text OneElement = M.fromList (("0001", OneElement "one" 1 )::("0002", OneElement "two" 2 )::("0003", OneElement "three" 3 )::("0004", OneElement "four" 4 ):: [])
let result = fmap(\i -> if i.key=="0001" then (OneElement "somethingelse" 1111) else i.value) map
```

Also how to access key/value in TextMap.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of `fmap` for `DA.Next.Map.Map` maps values only, not key, value pairs: `fmap : (v -> w) -> Map k v -> Map k w`. You could do a find and replace on values as follows:

```
import DA.Next.Map as M

data OneElement = OneElement with
  t : Text
  i : Int
    deriving (Eq, Show)

mymap : Map Text OneElement = M.fromList [("0001", OneElement "one" 1), ("0002", OneElement "two" 2), ("0003", OneElement "three" 3), ("0004", OneElement "four" 4)]
result = fmap (\i -> if i == OneElement "one" 1 then OneElement "somethingelse" 1111 else i) mymap
```

Note that I've renamed your `map` to `mymap`, as `map` overlaps with the standard library function `map: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

If you wanted to get your hands on key value pairs in a map-like function, you could write your own map function:

```
import DA.Next.Map as M

data OneElement = OneElement with
  t : Text
  i : Int
    deriving (Eq, Show)

mapEntries : MapKey k => ((k, v) -> w) -> Map k v -> Map k w
mapEntries f = M.fromList . map (\e -> (e._1, f e)) . M.toList

mymap : Map Text OneElement = M.fromList [("0001", OneElement "one" 1), ("0002", OneElement "two" 2), ("0003", OneElement "three" 3), ("0004", OneElement "four" 4)]
result = mapEntries (\(k, v) -> if k == "0001" then OneElement "somethingelse" 1111 else v) mymap
```

However, it looks like all you want to do is to replace the element at key `"0001"`. For that, you have the [`insert` function](https://docs.daml.com/daml/reference/base.html#function-da-next-map-insert-58471) in `DA.Next.Map`.

```
import DA.Next.Map as M

data OneElement = OneElement with
  t : Text
  i : Int
    deriving (Eq, Show)

mymap : Map Text OneElement = M.fromList [("0001", OneElement "one" 1), ("0002", OneElement "two" 2), ("0003", OneElement "three" 3), ("0004", OneElement "four" 4)]
result = insert "0001" (OneElement "somethingelse" 1111) mymap
```